# SharePoint: what does "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81071003)" mean?

Tags: sharepoint

Hallo,

i've got some code that imports documents into a SharePoint (WSS 3.0 SP1) document-library.
That code works most of the time without any problems, but sometimes the document is not imported into the document-library and i get this nasty exception instead.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Unable to update the information in the Microsoft Office document myFileName. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81071003): Unable to update the information in the Microsoft Office document myFileName.
bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish)
bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish)
```

What does this exception mean? And why does it occur only sometimes?

Thanks!

Comment: This probably belongs on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I asked the question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221160

Comment: Please migrate it to SO!

Answer (score 2):

Probably more appropriate for StackOverflow, but in summary it means that there is an issue with the .NET code that is communicating with Office (very crude explanation).

0x81071003 is a HRESULT code from a COM method which I'm guessing is called internally in the SP API.  Check the doc that you're feeding to SP when this exception is thrown, and maybe try to upload it manually to see if a more specific error is given.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same issue reported on [social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/8a7e3af3-167e-40d4-8c8b-a6a076f3cd97)

Will this solution work for you ?